# Spring SAML exception with Tomcat/ADFS integration

Tags: spring, security, spring-saml, adfs3.0

I downloaded the Sprind SAML sample app and its working fine in my local tomcat (against SSOCircle). Then I added a new SP to point to ADFS in our company. I was having several issues and solved them one by one. Now I am able to send the request and getting a valid saml response and assertion token as well. However i get the following error message:

I did follow some old threads (thanks to Vladimír Schäfer) and imported the public key to samlKeystore.jks and still getting the  same error. Any help is appreciated.

ERROR DETAILS:

- Canonicalized SignedInfo:
- QCZQsG03PFbYdFMyX2UaO2rXSXA=
- verify 1 References
- I am not requested to follow nested Manifests
- setElement("ds:Reference", "")
- setElement("ds:Transforms", "")
- Request for URI .w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1
- I was asked to create a ResourceResolver and got 0
- check resolvability by class org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver
- State I can resolve reference: "#_28691d8f-b0ab-4c19-ad32-4c60fada6e90"
- Try to catch an Element with ID _28691d8f-b0ab-4c19-ad32-4c60fada6e90 and Element was [Assertion: null]
- setElement("ds:Transform", "")
- Perform the (0)th .w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature transform
- setElement("ds:Transform", "")
- Pre-digested input:
- http://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/services/trustrobertRYYGWLoginrobertRurn:federation:authentication:windows
- Verification successful for URI "#_28691d8f-b0ab-4c19-ad32-4c60fada6e90"
- The Reference has Type
- Signature validated with key from supplied credential
- Signature validation using candidate credential was successful
- Successfully verified signature using KeyInfo-derived credential
- Attempting to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
- Failed to validate untrusted credential against trusted key
- Failed to validate untrusted credential against trusted key
- Failed to validate untrusted credential against trusted key
- Failed to establish trust of KeyInfo-derived credential
- Failed to verify signature and/or establish trust using any KeyInfo-derived credentials
- Attempting to verify signature using trusted credentials
- Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential
- Creating XMLSignature object
- Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: .w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
- Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
- signatureMethodURI = .w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
- jceSigAlgorithm    = SHA1withRSA
- jceSigProvider     = SunRsaSign
- PublicKey = Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23431177975394
  public exponent: 65537
- Canonicalized SignedInfo:
- QCZQsG03PFbYdFMyX2UaO2rXSXA=
- Signature verification failed.
- Signature did not validate against the credential's key
- Signature validation using candidate validation credential failed
  org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:79)
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine.verifySignature(BaseSignatureTrustEngine.java:142)
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:110)
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
  at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
- Attempting to validate signature using key from supplied credential
- Creating XMLSignature object
- Validating signature with signature algorithm URI: .w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
- Validation credential key algorithm 'RSA', key instance class 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl'
- signatureMethodURI = .w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
- jceSigAlgorithm    = SHA1withRSA
- jceSigProvider     = SunRsaSign
- PublicKey = Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 2179836566179054962
  public exponent: 65537
- Canonicalized SignedInfo:
- QCZQsG03PFbYdFMyX2UaO2rXSXA=
- Signature verification failed.
- Signature did not validate against the credential's key
- Signature validation using candidate validation credential failed
  org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:79)
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.BaseSignatureTrustEngine.verifySignature(BaseSignatureTrustEngine.java:142)
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:110)
  at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)

Answer (score 1):

Signature verification failed.
Signature did not validate against the credential's key
Signature validation using candidate validation credential failed org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key at

**This error occurs when you are trying to validate saml response or assertion with different publicKey and it signed with different public-private key pair.**
**First verify saml response signature x509 certificate and yours idp public certificate it will not be same.**

Answer (score 0):

below might help you, 
please verify your idp.xml has same public as your IDP/IDP Realm . Make sure IDP and Application in same timeZone/Time.